# How I can access to home CCTVS form laptop?

Tags: ip, nat, cctv

I want to see my CCTV camers at home, when i am not home, but I know the Publick Ip address and NAT address (private addreess) of CCTV registrator.

Manifacture of Camers is Hikvision

home I am using iVMS-4000 which working on my LAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basics for this question are not really for this site.

There are two relatively simple solutions: port forwarding and a VPN.

Using port forwarding basically places your camera on the Internet. There is an application called `shodan` that will quickly find your webcam and, unless you've taken appropriate measures, everyone will be able to try to hack them or see them. This may be an option if your CCTVs are on a separate LAN, they show nothing sensitive and you're able to do a quick factory reset regularly.

Security-wise, it would be better to set-up a VPN towards the network where the CCTVs are connected. Some Internet routers support this, or otherwise a simple Linux system will provide the VPN server.

It sometimes happens that devices that are not meant for access from the Internet refuse connection from outside their subnet (or simply do not have e default gateway defined). In that case, look for a reverse proxy.

Comment: Please don't write an answer on an obviously off topic question (you even flagged it as off topic)

Comment: I tried to give the answer some security content, but sorry, I won't do it again.